# Why does setState set wrong value to state?

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

Code is here, `date` is moment object:

```
 const date = this.state.date.clone().add(1, 'years');
 console.log(date); // Sat Jun 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0300
 this.setState({date}, () => console.log(this.state.date)); // Sun Jul 01 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0300
```

maybe it happens because of mutation? or wrong use of moment.js? any other ideas? please, help:)

Comment: date from state is moment object, i'm trying to add year to current state value

Comment: Are you sure? [It works for me](https://codesandbox.io/s/p95lj3w660).

Comment: the thing is that it adds a month to value

Comment: instead of year. I have this logic in different place, but the places are not related

Comment: it works if i remove .clone(). Didn't get it

Comment: It may be an issue with something else interfering. as you can see in @Tholle's link, it works in isolation. If it's not working **for you** you'll need to provide more info, (code and react version)

Answer (score 0):

here's the problem

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later.

source: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

the callback has old data, you should check for the value in your `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle hook instead

Comment: The callback has old data??

Comment: The callback or `componentDidUpdate` can be used.

Comment: **"does not always immediately update the component"** so it's not prudent to rely on the callback returning the correct data